# Button Click throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

When clicking the button, i recieve that error. .
**Form1 Class:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["modelConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand connect = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) From Users WHERE UserName = @user AND Password = @pass", sqlConnection);
        SqlParameter username = connect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userName.Text);
        SqlParameter password = connect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", passWord.Text);

        if ((int)connect.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
        {
            accessPic.BackgroundImage = Res.Accepted;
        }
        else
        {
            accessPic.BackgroundImage = Res.Denied;
        }
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

**Form1.Designer**

```
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(95, 90);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 8;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: Can you run this in Debug mode and see at which statement you get this error? I suspect it's the connection string call on the first line.

Comment: Use the debugger to see where the exception is raised. I assume that userName, passWord or accessPic is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step through the code in the debugger to find which line is throwing the exception and which object is null.

Also, you should refactor the code to use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ensure that the connection is disposed of once you're done with it.  The existing code will not close the connection if an exception is thrown between the opening and closing of the connection.  Here's how to do that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["modelConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand connect = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) From Users WHERE UserName = @user AND Password = @pass", sqlConnection))
        {
            SqlParameter username = connect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userName.Text);
            SqlParameter password = connect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", passWord.Text);

            if ((int)connect.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
            {
                accessPic.BackgroundImage = Res.Accepted;
            }
            else
            {
                accessPic.BackgroundImage = Res.Denied;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out i had misspelled the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Laurence

The connection string section should look like this:

```
<configuration> 
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="whatever" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
 <!-- more stuff here-->
```